# Use API to authenticate in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rest-client

I currently have a Rails application that is connected to an existing SQL database. I am using Devise for my user management, however the pre-existing User table in the database uses a very customized password encryption method.

There is a web service I can connect to that passes a JSON object with the login information to authenticate whether it is valid or not, and I have to manage my own session and everything after that.

I attempted to follow "[Railscast #250](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch?autoplay=true)", and combine it with Devise and some Stack Overflow searches, but things are not going very well.

This is what I have now, but it isn't doing anything, and I just don't feel like I am on the right track with this.

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    def new
        super
    end

    def create
        post_params = {
            "RuntimeEnvironment" => 1,
            "Email" => params[:session][:email],
            "Password" => params[:session][:password]
        }.to_json
        user_params = RestClient.post 'http://some.ip/WebServices', post_params, :content_type => "json"
        user = User.authenticate(user_params)
        if user
            session[:user_id] = user.user_id
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            flash.now.alert = "Invalid Username or Password"
            render "new"
        end
    end
end
```

This is the JSON Object returned if there is a successful login:

```
{"Success":true,"ErrorMessage":"","ResponseString":"","LoginResultData":{"FailMessage":"","ResultCode":0,"User":{"AccountCompleteFlag":1,"CreationDtime":"\/Date(1430848539000-0400)\/","DeleteFlag":0,"Email":"john@doe.com","FailedPasswordCount":1,"HistoricalFlag":0,"IsDirty":false,"IsAdminFlag":0,"IsSiteAdminFlag":0,"LastLoginDtime":"\/Date(1447789258000-0500)\/","NameFirst":"Ttest","NameLast":"test","Password":"TRQt3d2Z7caDsSKL0ARVRd8nInks+pIyTSqp3BLxUgg=","PasswordLockDtime":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/","PasswordLockFlag":0,"PasswordResetCode":"","PasswordResetStatus":0,"Phone":"1-X-5555555555-","RegistrationSource":"Registration","UserId":100029,"UserType":1,"PhoneInfo":{"AreaCode":"555","CountryCode":"X","Extension":"","FirstThree":"555","InternationalPhoneNumber":"","IsDirty":false,"IsInternational":false,"LastFour":"5555"}}}}
```

And what is returned for a failed one:

```
{"Success":true,"ErrorMessage":"","ResponseString":"","LoginResultData":{"FailMessage":"Invalid email address","ResultCode":1,"User":null}}
```

Is there a way where I can use Devise's session management while connecting to the API?

Comment: Do you know what exactly the RestClient.post returns?

Comment: I have updated my post.

Comment: A failed one would say "Success":true?

Comment: Success:true for connecting. It would tell me it's a failed login through "Result Code: 1" which is invalid email. Result Code 2 is invalid password. Result Code 0 is successful login.

Answer (score 0):

You can still authenticate through Devise using the email and password that the user provided. The RestClient would just be like a double check: just make sure that there are no routes that the user can authenticate through besides going through the RestClient. You can check this by doing `rake routes`.

For checking whether the result code was valid, you can do some JSON parsing as follows:

```
authentication_response = RestClient.post 'http://some.ip/WebServices', post_params, :content_type => "json"
json_authentication_response = JSON.parse(authentication_response)
result_code = json_authentication_response["LoginResultData"]["ResultCode"]
if result_code == 0
    # Authenticate
else
    # Don't authenticate
end
```

Comment: Wow that was immensely helpful, thank you. However, the parts that are really stumping me are how the Email and Password variables are passed in, and how to actually do the `#Authenticate`.

Comment: You can still use devises' authenticate method and pass in the email/password from the params. You would probably have to create your own strategy for handling what happens in devises' authenticate method though. Take a look at http://kyan.com/blog/2013/10/11/devise-authentication-strategies